# ObjectInstance to model class

Tags: c#

I am returning a object and I can't access to the property in that object. I only get method like gettype Equal and toString. I created a model that has the all the property on the object. Do I need to cast the object to the model?

```
UpdateSubscriptions = objSubscription.GetType<UpdateSubscriptions>()
```

Comment: what happened when you tried to cast object?

Comment: non-generic method objectGetype cannot be used  with the type of argument

Comment: This just simply isn't enough code to understand what you are trying to do.  Please see how to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need cast object to specif class try this.

```
// Example
UpdateSubscriptions UpdateSubscriptions;
if (objSubscription is UpdateSubscriptions updateSubscriptions)
{
    updateSubscriptions.MyProperty = 0;
    UpdateSubscriptions = updateSubscriptions;
}
```